# Can't make the border static as the screen changes size

Tags: html, css, border

I want a border around the image and caption which I have managed to create, but I don't want that border to get wider with the screen...which is what it's currently doing.

It's on codepen: https://codepen.io/nherdy/pen/xxGOoLZ?editors=1100

This is the html:

```
<div id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://assets.change.org/photos/8/hz/xi/DFHZxiusXbnKgqm-800x450-noPad.jpg?1517888048" alt="Collage of two pictures of Nicholas Winton">
    <figcaption id="img-caption"><strong>Nicholas Winton as a young man with one of the children he saved and later in
life</strong></figcaption>   </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#img-div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 30px solid white;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe 30px is a lot decrease that...otherwise please include more information about your problem!

Comment: It is not the border that changes size, but the container holding the picture. The container should have a cyan background, the image a white border and a border-radius.